# Parallelizing a large amount of Bitmap.Clone operations

Tags: c#, multithreading, image-processing, bitmap, parallel.foreach

I have dictionary of lists of objects, and for each list I need to load a bitmap using the associated key, and for each object in the list, calculate a transform, clone the bitmap using the transform, and save the result. The amount of objects in each list varies from 60,000 to one sometimes, and doing it serially will most likely take forever. So, I tried parallelizing the for each loop in each list, but unfortunately, the Bitmap class holds a global lock, and so, to avoid an exception, I have to place a lock on the cloning and saving code, which really defeats the point of using a parallel loop in the first place, as the cloning and saving is the most time-consuming part of the process. Is there a way I can get a subimage of a bitmap in multiple threads?

Comment: To avoid locking issues with the `Bitmap`, consider converting the initial `Bitmap` to `byte[]` and passing that around instead of the `Bitmap`.  This adds an extra step before cloning--you have to recreate the `Bitmap` from a `MemoryStream`--but then you have a `Bitmap` you're free to play with on the processing thread.  The benefits of parallel processing may make up for the extra step; you could test to find out.

Comment: Still though, at the most you'll get a 2x, 4x, or 8x speedup (depending on how many CPU cores your machine has), and if this is slow when done serially, it'll be pretty slow when done in parallel.

Comment: How are you cloning the bitmap? If you're using `GetPixel`/`SetPixel` you're going to have perf issues. Have you tried `LockBits`?

Comment: @Dai, true, `LockBits` is faster, but saving the file will likely be orders of magnitude slower than copying the image anyway...

Comment: @adv12 The bitmaps involved are large, and including bitmap overhead, I doubt I have the memory for a bitmap for each thread. I tried a similar approach, and I just got OutOfMemory errors.

Comment: @Dai, I am using the Bitmap.Clone method to clone it.

Comment: How many threads were you starting at once?  Or were you just creating `Task`s and letting TPL manage that?

Comment: @adv12, I was just using Parallel.ForEach, and letting whatever witchcraft lies beneath that to run it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the real answer, for me at least, is to drop GDI+, and use [Magick.NET](https://magick.codeplex.com/), which is better designed for this. Now it works perfectly, with multithreading and the expected speedup.